# Google Cloud Storage atomic creation of a Blob

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using [haddop-connectors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors)
project for writing BLOBs to Google Cloud Storage.

I'd like to make sure that a BLOB with a specific *target name* that is being written in a concurrent context is either written in FULL or not appearing at all as visible in case that an exception has occurred while writing.

In the code below, in case that that an I/O exception occurs, the BLOB written will appear on GCS because the stream is being closed in `finally`:

```
        val stream = fs.create(path, overwrite)
        try {
            actions.map(_ + "\n").map(_.getBytes(UTF_8)).foreach(stream.write)
        } finally {
            stream.close()
        }
```

The other possibility would be to not close the stream and let it "leak" so that the BLOB does not get created. However this is not really a valid option.

```
        val stream = fs.create(path, overwrite)
        actions.map(_ + "\n").map(_.getBytes(UTF_8)).foreach(stream.write)
        stream.close()
```

Can anybody share with me a recipe on how to write to GCS a BLOB either with [hadoop-connectors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors) or [cloud storage client](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage)  in an atomic fashion?

Answer (score 1):

I have used reflection within [hadoop-connectors](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors) to retrieve an instance of `com.google.api.services.storage.Storage` from the `GoogleHadoopFileSystem` instance

```
    GoogleCloudStorage googleCloudStorage =  ghfs.getGcsFs().getGcs();
    Field gcsField = googleCloudStorage.getClass().getDeclaredField("gcs");
    gcsField.setAccessible(true);
    Storage gcs = (Storage) gcsField.get(googleCloudStorage);
```

in order to have the ability to make a call based on an input stream corresponding to the data in memory.

```
private static StorageObject createBlob(URI blobPath, byte[] content, GoogleHadoopFileSystem ghfs, Storage gcs)
        throws IOException
{
    CreateFileOptions createFileOptions = new CreateFileOptions(false);
    CreateObjectOptions createObjectOptions = objectOptionsFromFileOptions(createFileOptions);
    PathCodec pathCodec = ghfs.getGcsFs().getOptions().getPathCodec();
    StorageResourceId storageResourceId = pathCodec.validatePathAndGetId(blobPath, false);

    StorageObject object =
            new StorageObject()
                    .setContentEncoding(createObjectOptions.getContentEncoding())
                    .setMetadata(encodeMetadata(createObjectOptions.getMetadata()))
                    .setName(storageResourceId.getObjectName());

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content, 0, content.length);
    Storage.Objects.Insert insert = gcs.objects().insert(
            storageResourceId.getBucketName(),
            object,
            new InputStreamContent(createObjectOptions.getContentType(), inputStream));
    // The operation succeeds only if there are no live versions of the blob. 
    insert.setIfGenerationMatch(0L);
    insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
    insert.setName(storageResourceId.getObjectName());
    return insert.execute();
}

/**
 * Helper for converting from a Map&lt;String, byte[]&gt; metadata map that may be in a
 * StorageObject into a Map&lt;String, String&gt; suitable for placement inside a
 * GoogleCloudStorageItemInfo.
 */
@VisibleForTesting
static Map<String, String> encodeMetadata(Map<String, byte[]> metadata) {
    return Maps.transformValues(metadata, QuickstartParallelApiWriteExample::encodeMetadataValues);
}

// A function to encode metadata map values
private static String encodeMetadataValues(byte[] bytes) {
    return bytes == null ? Data.NULL_STRING : BaseEncoding.base64().encode(bytes);
}
```

Note in the example above, that even if there are multiple callers trying to create a blob with the same name in parallel, ONE and only ONE will succeed in creating the blob. The other callers will receive `412 Precondition Failed`.

Comment: Good to see you figured it out. Seems `insert.setIfGenerationMatch(0L)` is the key.

Comment: Could you add a link to the `Storage.Objects.Insert` class? I searched but didn't find it in the Java client library?

Answer (score 0):

GCS objects (blobs) are immutable [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability), which means they can be created, deleted or replaced, but not appended.

The Hadoop GCS connector provides the HCFS interface which gives the illusion of appendable files. But under the hood, it is just one blob creation, GCS doesn't know if the content is complete or not from the application's perspective, just as you mentioned in the example. There is no way to cancel a file creation.

There are 2 options you can consider:

1. Create a temp blob/file, copy it to the final blob/file, then delete the temp blob/file, see [2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#rename). Note that there is no atomic rename operation in GCS, rename is implemented as copy-then-delete.
2. If your data fits into the memory, first read up the stream and buffer the bytes in memory, then create the blob/file, see [3](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-storage/latest/com.google.cloud.storage.Storage#com_google_cloud_storage_Storage_create_com_google_cloud_storage_BlobInfo_byte___com_google_cloud_storage_Storage_BlobTargetOption____).

GCS connector should also work with the 2 options above, but I think GCS client library gives you more control.

Comment: The option related to writing to a tmp file and then rename it to the destination file is not viable. I tested the scenario and multiple renames of tmp files towards the destination file (when it doesn't yet exist) can be performed in parallel. Creating the Blob over java-storage library does seem to be the option at hand. In my specific file we're speaking about a JSON file which definitely fits in memory. Is there any chance to achieve the blob creation with the hadoop-connectors library?

Comment: Is the operation from reference [3](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-storage/latest/com.google.cloud.storage.Storage#com_google_cloud_storage_Storage_create_com_google_cloud_storage_BlobInfo_byte___com_google_cloud_storage_Storage_BlobTargetOption____) guaranteed to be atomic (either write the whole file content or fail)? Also only 1 thread will succeed the call in a parallel context ?

Comment: Do you mean in your use case there can be multiple temp files which get renamed to the same destination file? I believe create is atomic.

Comment: My use case is about creating a transaction log file for a table. Due to the fact that multiple processes can create the transaction log file in a concurrent context, ONE and only ONE needs to succeed in doing so. Also writing the transaction log file should not stop mid-write due to I/O exceptions because this would leave the table corrupt.

Comment: In the underlying implementation of the hadoop-connectors I see that the cloud storage client library is being actually used. I'm still trying to find out a way to "abort" the operation instead of closing the stream and persisting a blob mid-written.